# display resource in j2ee web app by using url

Tags: java, url, jakarta-ee, war

i have simple j2ee web app. i packed it to a war file. The structure of war file is :

```
/..
 images
 css
 WEB-INF
     web.xml
 wsdl
    abc.wsdl
 .....
```

i deployed it into ServiceMix (it uses jetty for web container). the app worked just fine.

now, my question is:
  How can i display abc.wsdl file by using URL like:

```
http://localhost:8080/simpleapp/wsdl/abc.wsdl
```

I know this is not a good practice, but i just want to know how to do this.

Comment: What happens when you try that URL?

Answer (score 0):

try the following in

click here to view wsdl file

in any of the generated jsp / index.html which is rooted at the base of the webapp

Comment: Thanks. I figured it out:
In web.xml, add those line: 
    

    <mime-mapping>
  <extension>wsdl</extension>
  <mime-type>text/xml</mime-type>
 </mime-mapping>

So when you access the wsdl file, it will display the file (instead of show dialog to ask for downloading.)